# Realm error: "Primary key property 'Product.upc' has duplicate values after migration."

Tags: swift, migration, realm, kvc

I have a pre-production Swift app that is using Realm.  It has a class named `Product` with the primary key set as "upc".  I modified the class to add some additional variables and then tried to run migration. Now when I try to run the app I am getting the following error:

> ```
> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: 
> Error Domain=io.realm Code=1 "Primary key property 'Product.upc' has duplicate values after migration."
> ```

I understand that I cannot have duplicate key values but it's not clear how I get around this without modifying the upc values to some new value which is not acceptable.  Is there some other way to just migrate, reset or, delete the schema to get around this?

I have tried to remove the realm file and start over but I am missing something as this just reoccurs after I start it all up again.

#### `Product` class:

```
    @objc dynamic var upc: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var itemDescription: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var originalQty: Int = 0
    //@objc dynamic var totalOriginalCost: String
    //@objc dynamic var totalOriginalRetail: String
    //@objc dynamic var vendorStyle: String
    @objc dynamic var color: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var size: String = ""
    //@objc dynamic var clientCost: String
    //@objc dynamic var totalClientCost: String
    //@objc dynamic var division: String
    //@objc dynamic var departmentName: String
    //@objc dynamic var vendorName: String
    @objc dynamic var image: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot1: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot2: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot3: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot4: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot5: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot6: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot7: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot8: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot9: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot10: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot11: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot12: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot13: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot14: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageSlot15: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var price: Double = 0
    @objc dynamic var shipping: Double = 0
    @objc dynamic var brand: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var style: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var sleeveStyle: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var sleeveLength: String = ""


    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "upc"
    }
    }
```

#### `migration` code:

```
// bump the schema version to 1
schemaVersion: 1,
migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Product.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
        }
    }
})
```

> ```
> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=1 "Primary key property 'Product.upc' has duplicate values after migration."
> ```

Update: I tried the following code to reset the schema but then I get new errors:

```
var config = Realm.Configuration() config.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = true
```

> ```
> error:
> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=10 "Migration is required due to the following errors:
> - Property 'Product.upc' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.itemDescription' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.originalQty' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.color' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.size' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.image' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot1' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot2' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot3' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot10' has been added.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot5' has been added.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot6' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot7' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot8' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot9' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot4' has been added.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot11' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot12' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot13' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot14' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.imageSlot15' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.price' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.shipping' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.brand' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.style' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.sleeveStyle' has been made required.
> - Property 'Product.sleeveLength' has been made required.
> ```

Comment: If you are adding or removing object properties, you don't need to enumerate over those objects in the migration block. It will automatically detect those changes and update the schema accordingly. So if you delete *all* of the realm files (there are more then 1), reset to your schema to 0 and re-run the app, you're still getting that error? Are you certain you removed the lock and management files as well?

Comment: I removed the enumeration, deleted all the realm files including lock and management then reset the schema to 0 and ran the app.  I get another fatal error that I pasted above about the Product class and it's objects now have been made required.  The error also says that migration is required.  So I bumped the schema to 1 and run again.  The error about the duplicate keys comes back.

Comment: Is this a Query or Full Sync realm or just local? and is sandboxing turned on or off?

Comment: just local and sandboxing is off.

Comment: The code that's throwing the error is missing from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all data in your database then update schema **Add, update filed** after update your database must set new version

**Code for update version**

```
export default new Realm({
  schema: [class1, class2, classN],
  schemaVersion: 2 // set new version 
});
```

**Code for remove all data**

```
try {
      realm.beginTransaction();
      realm.deleteAll();
      realm.commitTransaction();
 } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
 }
```